# unique_ptr< T[] >をforeach文で使用する方法をご教授お願いします。

Tags: c++, c++11

私は今、unique_ptrを用いてメモリ管理を行っています。
その際、unique_ptrで配列を動的確保し、それをforeach文で回す方法があるかどうか知りたいです。

具体的には、

```
unique_ptr < int[] > foo = make_unique< int[] >(20);
for(auto& a : foo){
    a = 0;
}
```

のような感じです。
unique_ptrにはイテレータが用意されていないので、私の知識ではこのような処理を記述することができませんが、配列の要素数を気にせず使えるので、出来ればforeach文で処理したいと考えています。
C++はまだ１年も触ってない初心者ですので、解りにくい表現や、間違えて認識している部分を多々あるとは思いますが、どなたかご教授願います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> unique_ptrで配列を動的確保し、それをforeach文で回す方法があるかどうか知りたいです。

ありません。

（ちなみに、C++には"foreach文"は存在しないので、range-based for構文か[`std::for_each`アルゴリズム](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/for_each.html)ですね。）

スマートポインタ`unique_ptr<T[]>`には配列要素数を管理する機構がないため、別変数を使って要素数を管理しなければなりません。また、要素走査には古典的forループが必要です。

```
size_t num = 20;
unique_ptr<int[]> foo = make_unique<int[]>(num);
for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    auto& a = foo[i];
    a = 0;
}
```

なので、通常は可変長配列`vector<T>`の利用をお勧めします。

---

おまけ：C++ランタイムライブラリは、配列の解放処理`delete[]`を正しく行うために、[その要素数を知っています](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array)。ただし、プログラムからこの情報にアクセスする方法は存在しません。

Answer (score 3):

yohjpさんの述べているとおり`unique_ptr`では要素数を知る方法がないため、別途要素数を自分で保存しておくことで実現することになります。要素数が分かれば、ラッパークラスを作ることで対応可能です。

以下のコードでは、そのようなラッパーとしてクラステンプレート`boost::iterator_range`およびそれを作成するヘルパ関数`boost::make_iterator_range`を使っています。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main()
{
    int n = 20;
    auto foo = std::make_unique<int[]>(n);
    for (auto& a : boost::make_iterator_range(foo.get(), foo.get() + n))
    {
        a = 0;
    }
}
```

Boostライブラリを使えなかったり使いたくなかったりする場合には、自作することになります。メンバ関数`begin`および`end`が存在するだけでよいので、比較的作成は容易だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

他の方も言っているように、使用するクラスを変えるか、ラッパーを作成する。
boostが使えない or どのように作るか知りたい場合の為、C++標準でどのように書けるか、最低限のサンプルのつもりで置いておく。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


// unique_wrapperとmake_unique_wrapperを作るためのヘルパ - かなり手抜きその1.
// 配列か判定する - 結果はvalueが1 or 0で判別.
template <class vType> struct is_array {
    enum { value = 0 }; // falseである.
};
template <class vType> struct is_array<vType[]> {
    enum { value = 1 }; // trueである.
};
// trueのときだけ型が存在する - SFINAEに用いる.
template <bool Condition, class vType>
struct condition_type {};
template <class vType>
struct condition_type<true, vType> {
    using type = vType;
};
// 型から配列要素を抜く - 配列じゃなければ元のままに.
template <class vType>
struct remove_array {
    using type = vType;
};
template <class vType>
struct remove_array<vType[]> {
    using type = vType;
};

// 通常版と配列版を同時にラッピングしている分、若干危険かもしれない･･･？.
template <class vType>
class unique_wrapper : public std::unique_ptr<vType> {
    std::size_t num_array;
    using MyType = unique_wrapper<vType>;
    using PtrType = typename remove_array<vType>::type;
public:
    unique_wrapper(MyType const &) = delete;
    // 1個版と配列版と両方のコンストラクタを持つ - make_unique_wrapperのfriendにしてprivate化するか？.
    unique_wrapper(PtrType *ptr) : std::unique_ptr<vType>(ptr), num_array(1){}
    unique_wrapper(PtrType *ptr, std::size_t num) : std::unique_ptr<vType>(ptr), num_array(num){}
    unique_wrapper(MyType &&rhs) : std::unique_ptr<vType>(rhs.release()), num_array(rhs.num_array){}

    // 最低限このようなインターフェースを持つiteratorと
    class iterator {
        PtrType *ptr_;
    public:
        iterator(PtrType *ptr) : ptr_(ptr){}
        ~iterator(){}

        PtrType *operator ++(){ ++ptr_; return ptr_; }
        PtrType &operator *(){ return *ptr_; }
        bool operator !=(iterator rhs){ return *ptr_ != *rhs; }
    };
    // 上記を戻すbeginとendというインターフェースがあればrange-based forは動く.
    iterator begin(){ return this->get(); }
    iterator end(){ return this->get() + num_array; }
};

// make_unique_wrapper自体の各種 - かなり手抜きその2.
template <class vType>
unique_wrapper<typename condition_type<is_array<vType>::value == 1, vType>::type> make_unique_wrapper(std::size_t n){
    unique_wrapper<vType> wrap(new typename remove_array<vType>::type[n], n);
    return wrap;
}
template <class vType, class ...Args>
unique_wrapper<typename condition_type<is_array<vType>::value == 0, vType>::type> make_unique_wrapper(Args... args){
    unique_wrapper<vType> wrap(new vType((args)...));
    return wrap;
}


struct Foo {
    ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "Foo destructor." << std::endl;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << "My name is Foo." << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    // use test code.
    {
        unique_wrapper<int[]> ptr = make_unique_wrapper<int[]>(7);
        {
            for (auto &n : ptr){
                std::cout << "Please number and enter : ";
                std::cin >> n;
            }
        }

        for (auto n : ptr){
            std::cout << n << std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.get();
    }   // この段階でちゃんとdelete[]が働く.
    {
        // 折角なんでFooさんでテスト.
        unique_wrapper<Foo> ptr = make_unique_wrapper<Foo>();
        ptr->print();
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

※コード書き直した。前の状態だと、破棄する場面で正しく破棄できない(配列版unique_ptrが使用されない)のに、make_unique_wrapperで指定できるのは配列作成のみだったのでちぐはぐな状態だった。
書き直した現状でも、想定通りのmake_unique_wrapperやmake_unique_wrapper以外の書き方への正しいエラー化を行ってはおらず、あくまで知識のたたき台として用意。
大事なのは、最低限あれだけのインターフェース(iteratorのoperatorとunique_wrapperのbeginとend)を作りさえすればrange-based-forに投げ込めるという部分である。

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr`でなく`vector`を使いましょう。

```
vector<int> foo(20);
for(auto& a : foo) {
    a = 0;
}
```